# Issue with calling Spritebatch in XNA 4.0 Game

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, spritebatch

So, I am creating a game in XNA 4.0, using the program Microsoft Visual C# Studio Express 2010.

The issue I am having: I have the entire game done, and there is no reason why it should not be working.

The issue is that every time I try to debug my game, it tells me that I am missing a 'Spritebatch.end' or a 'Spritebatch.begin' in random areas in my code.  If I put in a 'Spritebatch.end', it tells me I am missing a 'Spritebatch.begin', and vice versa.  I have gone over the source code of this repeatedly, and there is no syntax error.

So my question is:  Is there an issue with the program I am using, or is there some other reason my code is giving me this rather circular error?

Here is what I have right now:  I have implemented other fixes but nothing has worked.

```
private void DrawEmptyPiece(int pixelX, int pixelY)
    {

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(
            playingPieces,
            new Rectangle(pixelX, pixelY,
                GamePiece.PieceWidth, GamePiece.PieceHeight),
                EmptyPiece,
                Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();



    }

    private void DrawStandardPiece(int x, int y,
        int pixelX, int pixelY)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(
            playingPieces, new Rectangle(pixelX, pixelY,
                GamePiece.PieceWidth, GamePiece.PieceHeight),
                gameBoard.GetSourceRect(x, y),
                Color.White);

    }

    private void DrawFallingPiece(int pixelX, int pixelY,
        string positionName)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(
            playingPieces,
            new Rectangle(pixelX, pixelY -
                gameBoard.fallingPieces[positionName].VerticalOffset,
                GamePiece.PieceWidth, GamePiece.PieceHeight),
                gameBoard.fallingPieces[positionName].GetSourceRect(),
                Color.White);
    }

    private void DrawFadingPiece(int pixelX, int pixelY,
        string positionName)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(
            playingPieces,
            new Rectangle(pixelX, pixelY,
                GamePiece.PieceWidth, GamePiece.PieceHeight),
                gameBoard.fadingPieces[positionName].GetSourceRect(),
                Color.White *
                gameBoard.fadingPieces[positionName].alphaLevel);
    }

    private void DrawRotatingPiece(int pixelX, int pixelY,
        string positionName)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(
            playingPieces,
            new Rectangle(pixelX + (GamePiece.PieceWidth / 2),
                pixelY + (GamePiece.PieceHeight / 2),
                GamePiece.PieceWidth,
                GamePiece.PieceHeight),
                gameBoard.rotatingPieces[positionName].GetSourceRect(),
                Color.White,
                gameBoard.rotatingPieces[positionName].RotationAmount,
                new Vector2(GamePiece.PieceWidth / 2,
                    GamePiece.PieceHeight / 2),
                    SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
    }
```

And the rest of the code.

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        foreach (ScoreZoom zoom in ScoreZooms)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(pericles36Font, zoom.Text,
                new Vector2(this.Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2,
                    this.Window.ClientBounds.Height / 2),
                    zoom.DrawColor, 0.0f,
                    new Vector2(pericles36Font.MeasureString(zoom.Text).X / 2,
                    pericles36Font.MeasureString(zoom.Text).Y / 2),
            zoom.Scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
        }

        if (gameState == GameStates.TitleScreen)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(titleScreen,
                new Rectangle(0, 0,
                    this.Window.ClientBounds.Width,
                    this.Window.ClientBounds.Height),
                    Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < GameBoard.GameBoardWidth; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < GameBoard.GameBoardHeight; y++)
            {
                int pixelX = (int)gameBoardDisplayOrigin.X +
                    (x * GamePiece.PieceWidth);
                int pixelY = (int)gameBoardDisplayOrigin.Y +
                    (y * GamePiece.PieceHeight);


               DrawEmptyPiece(pixelX, pixelY);

                bool pieceDrawn = false;

                string positionName = x.ToString() + "_" + y.ToString();

                if (gameBoard.rotatingPieces.ContainsKey(positionName))
                {
                    DrawRotatingPiece(pixelX, pixelY, positionName);
                    pieceDrawn = true;
                }

                if (gameBoard.fadingPieces.ContainsKey(positionName))
                {
                    DrawFadingPiece(pixelX, pixelY, positionName);
                    pieceDrawn = true;
                }

                if (gameBoard.fallingPieces.ContainsKey(positionName))
                {
                    DrawFallingPiece(pixelX, pixelY, positionName);
                    pieceDrawn = true;
                }

                if (!pieceDrawn)
                {
                    DrawStandardPiece(x, y, pixelX, pixelY);
                }
            }

        spriteBatch.DrawString(pericles36Font,
         playerScore.ToString(),
         scorePosition,
         Color.Black);


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: You should check around for .Begin() and .End() and make sure that they match. This is easiest if you set a breakpoint at the first .Begin() and then step through until you are done. 
Odds are that somewhere you end the SpriteBatch in a component.
The easiest way to avoid this is if you only have ONE Begin() and ONE End() in your Game's Draw() method. In between these two calls you should ask all components and subsystems to draw themselves using a reference to the original SpriteBatch.

Comment: Extended discussion has been [imported to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13020/discussion-between-leggy7-and-halcyonixus).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when your `Draw(GameTime gameTime)` is like

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) 
    {     
     spriteBatch.Begin(); 

     foreach (ScoreZoom zoom in ScoreZooms) 
     { 
      spriteBatch.DrawString(pericles36Font, zoom.Text, 
      new Vector2(this.Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2, 
      this.Window.ClientBounds.Height / 2), 
      zoom.DrawColor, 0.0f, 
      new Vector2(pericles36Font.MeasureString(zoom.Text).X / 2, 
      pericles36Font.MeasureString(zoom.Text).Y / 2), 
      zoom.Scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f); 
     } 

     spriteBatch.DrawString(pericles36Font, 
     playerScore.ToString(), 
     scorePosition, 
     Color.Black); 

     spriteBatch.End(); 
     base.Draw(gameTime); 
    }
```

I would recommend to move the `spriteBatch.Draw(...)` code from the private methods into your `Draw(GameTime gameTime)` and to comment all those private methods